# How does the optimizer treat a call to a scalar function with the same parameter values?

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where I use an scalar function.  The value of the only function parameter is taken from a field in my query (like this):

```
SELECT
    fn_MyFunc(MyField)
FROM MyTable
```

If there are several thousand rows in this table, and there are only a few distinct values in `MyField`, is the optimizer smart enough to know that it has seen that value before or will it still execute the function over and over again?

Comment: Pretty sure it does not cache that info, unless the parameters are fixed at the time the query is compiled.

Comment: You say inline function but the syntax you are using seems more like a scalar UDF. These are not inline. The only inline functions are TVFs. Sometimes converting a scalar UDF to an inline function can improve performance as here [Scalar functions, inlining, and performance](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/08/04/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post.aspx)

Comment: Martin: You are right.  Question has been edited.

Comment: Here is a related blogpost. [T-SQL User-Defined Functions: the good, the bad, and the ugly (part 1)](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2012/05/20/t-sql-user-defined-functions-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User defined function stores the execution plan only. No optimiser in existence would be able to cache this useful information. The scalar udf is a black box.  the optimizer will not manually memoize UDFs for you.

Solution to increase performance if function is Deterministic means that the same inputs return the same output independent of time and database:

Create a table for all possible results of this UDF and JOIN the table this with the query. It will give best performance/

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no, it's not smart enough, and yes it will execute the function as many times as it is called.

If you can create distinct values using a derived table, it might improve performance:

```
SELECT fn_MyFunc(distinct_field) 
FROM (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT MyField as distinct_field
     FROM MyTable) tbl
```

Also, unwrapping the function's code and embedding it in the query might help.